Not able to change keybindings in codesandbox devbox
Recently keybindings for codesandbox's devbox got reset and now I am unable to change it.
I am getting this error when trying to change:
Error 'Error: Unable to write to the keybindings configuration file. Please open it to correct errors/warnings in the file and try again.' while editing the keybinding. Please open 'keybindings.json' file and check for errors.

I reckon its because some vscode update messed codesandbox, anyone knows any workaround? I don't like default keybindings, some of the defaults themselves aren't working like "Toggle tasks and terminals".
